# FedEx Dry Ice via FedEx API

Tags: fedex

Is anyone familiar enough with the FedEx API to get Dry Ice to work?

The FedEx documentation for Dry Ice is here: https://www.fedex.com/us/developer/WebHelp/ws/2014/dvg/WS_DVG_WebHelp/index.htm#25_2_Dry_Ice_Coding_Details.htm

This doesn't seem to really match their WSDL however. No matter what I've tried I'm always getting back a schema validation error.

Is anyone able to provide a sample request including dry ice with a successful response?

I cannot find any information on where the correct place to put the RequestedPackages element is. I put it on the same level as RequestedShipment as well as several other places and got nowhere.

If I put only the RequestedShipment fields in place and not the package info I get:

```
8616 (Dry Ice cannot be entered at the shipment level.)
```

**Sample Request**

This Sample request feels the closest I've gotten. FedEx does not like the position of the `RequestedPackages` element though. I've taken out a lot of the unnecessary fields like address information below:

```
    <ns:ProcessShipmentRequest xmlns:ns="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v15" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v15 ShipService v15.xsd">
    <ns:WebAuthenticationDetail>
        <ns:UserCredential>
        </ns:UserCredential>
    </ns:WebAuthenticationDetail>
    <ns:ClientDetail>
    </ns:ClientDetail>
    <ns:TransactionDetail>
        <ns:CustomerTransactionId>CreatePendingRequest</ns:CustomerTransactionId>
    </ns:TransactionDetail>
    <ns:Version>
        <ns:ServiceId>ship</ns:ServiceId>
        <ns:Major>15</ns:Major>
        <ns:Intermediate>0</ns:Intermediate>
        <ns:Minor>0</ns:Minor>
    </ns:Version>
    <ns:RequestedShipment>
        <ns:ShipTimestamp>2016-10-21T10:17:09-07:00</ns:ShipTimestamp>
        <ns:DropoffType>REGULAR_PICKUP</ns:DropoffType>
        <ns:ServiceType>PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT</ns:ServiceType>
        <ns:PackagingType>YOUR_PACKAGING</ns:PackagingType>
        <ns:SpecialServicesRequested>
            <ns:SpecialServiceTypes>DRY_ICE</ns:SpecialServiceTypes>
            <ns:ShipmentDryIceDetail>
                <ns:PackageCount>1</ns:PackageCount>
                <ns:TotalWeight>
                    <ns:Units>KG</ns:Units>
                    <ns:Value>2.5</ns:Value>
                </ns:TotalWeight>
            </ns:ShipmentDryIceDetail>
        </ns:SpecialServicesRequested>
        <ns:LabelSpecification>
            <ns:LabelFormatType>COMMON2D</ns:LabelFormatType>
            <ns:ImageType>ZPLII</ns:ImageType>
            <ns:LabelStockType>STOCK_4X6</ns:LabelStockType>
            <ns:LabelPrintingOrientation>TOP_EDGE_OF_TEXT_FIRST</ns:LabelPrintingOrientation>
        </ns:LabelSpecification>
        <ns:RateRequestTypes>LIST</ns:RateRequestTypes>
        <ns:PackageCount>1</ns:PackageCount>
        <ns:RequestedPackageLineItems>
            <ns:SequenceNumber>1</ns:SequenceNumber>
            <ns:Weight>
                <ns:Units>LB</ns:Units>
                <ns:Value>8</ns:Value>
            </ns:Weight>
            <ns:Dimensions>
            </ns:Dimensions>
            <ns:SpecialServicesRequested>
                <ns:SpecialServiceTypes>SIGNATURE_OPTION</ns:SpecialServiceTypes>
                <ns:SignatureOptionDetail>
                    <ns:OptionType>SERVICE_DEFAULT</ns:OptionType>
                </ns:SignatureOptionDetail>
            </ns:SpecialServicesRequested>
        </ns:RequestedPackageLineItems>
    </ns:RequestedShipment>
    <ns:RequestedPackages>
        <ns:SpecialServicesRequested>
            <ns:SpecialServiceTypes>DRY_ICE</ns:SpecialServiceTypes>
            <ns:DryIceWeight>
                <ns:Units>KG</ns:Units>
                <ns:Value>2.5</ns:Value>
            </ns:DryIceWeight>
        </ns:SpecialServicesRequested>
    </ns:RequestedPackages>
</ns:ProcessShipmentRequest>
```

FedEx Response:

```
Element not allowed: RequestedPackages@http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v15 in element ProcessShipmentRequest@http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v15
```

I've also tried putting the package level dry ice info in the `RequestedPackageLineItems/SpecialServicesRequested` section, but got the following response:

```
Expected elements \'PieceCountVerificationBoxCount@http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v15 PriorityAlertDetail@http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v15 AlcoholDetail@http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v15\' instead of \'DryIceWeight@http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v15\' here in element SpecialServicesRequested@http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v15
```

Comment: If you could share your code, or at least the salient parts, that would help

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Please anybody who have experience working with FedEx and Dry should post here. Thanks

Comment: Here is the code i have started from the documenation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is a sample FedEx Label Request with Dry Ice which works. Credentials and address information have been removed.

Dry ice info goes in `RequestedShipment/RequestedPackageLineItems/SpecialServicesRequested`

While the Documentation also says to put it in `RequestedShipment/SpecialServicesRequested` I found that doing so would always lead to the following error

```
8616 (Dry Ice cannot be entered at the shipment level.)
```

Also note that this package also has `SIGNATURE_OPTION` enabled. The ordering of these and any other `SpecialServiceTypes` is extremely important. If you are using other Package level Special Services and are getting a `Schema validation failed for request` error, you may need to re-order the fields or contact FedEx support for help in the ordering. `DRY_ICE` must always be the first Special Service Type and the `DryIceWeight` element must come after the list of special services, but before any of the extra elements those Services require.

**Sample Dry Ice shipment request:**

```
<ns:ProcessShipmentRequest xmlns:ns="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v15" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v15 ShipService v15.xsd">
    <ns:WebAuthenticationDetail>
        <ns:UserCredential>
            <ns:Key></ns:Key>
            <ns:Password></ns:Password>
        </ns:UserCredential>
    </ns:WebAuthenticationDetail>
    <ns:ClientDetail>
        <ns:AccountNumber></ns:AccountNumber>
        <ns:MeterNumber></ns:MeterNumber>
    </ns:ClientDetail>
    <ns:TransactionDetail>
        <ns:CustomerTransactionId>CreatePendingRequest</ns:CustomerTransactionId>
    </ns:TransactionDetail>
    <ns:Version>
        <ns:ServiceId>ship</ns:ServiceId>
        <ns:Major>15</ns:Major>
        <ns:Intermediate>0</ns:Intermediate>
        <ns:Minor>0</ns:Minor>
    </ns:Version>
    <ns:RequestedShipment>
        <ns:ShipTimestamp>2016-10-25T11:03:40-07:00</ns:ShipTimestamp>
        <ns:DropoffType>REGULAR_PICKUP</ns:DropoffType>
        <ns:ServiceType>PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT</ns:ServiceType>
        <ns:PackagingType>YOUR_PACKAGING</ns:PackagingType>
        <ns:Shipper>
            <ns:Contact>
                <ns:CompanyName>Name</ns:CompanyName>
                <ns:PhoneNumber>Phone</ns:PhoneNumber>
            </ns:Contact>
            <ns:Address>
                <ns:StreetLines>Street</ns:StreetLines>
                <ns:StreetLines>Street</ns:StreetLines>
                <ns:City>City</ns:City>
                <ns:StateOrProvinceCode>CA</ns:StateOrProvinceCode>
                <ns:PostalCode>ZIP</ns:PostalCode>
                <ns:CountryCode>US</ns:CountryCode>
            </ns:Address>
        </ns:Shipper>
        <ns:Recipient>
            <ns:Contact>
                <ns:PersonName>Name</ns:PersonName>
                <ns:PhoneNumber>Phone</ns:PhoneNumber>
            </ns:Contact>
            <ns:Address>
                <ns:StreetLines>123 MAIN STREET</ns:StreetLines>
                <ns:StreetLines>MAIL SLOT 45</ns:StreetLines>
                <ns:City>City</ns:City>
                <ns:StateOrProvinceCode>CA</ns:StateOrProvinceCode>
                <ns:PostalCode>Xip</ns:PostalCode>
                <ns:CountryCode>US</ns:CountryCode>
            </ns:Address>
        </ns:Recipient>
        <ns:ShippingChargesPayment>
            <ns:PaymentType>SENDER</ns:PaymentType>
            <ns:Payor>
                <ns:ResponsibleParty>
                    <ns:AccountNumber></ns:AccountNumber>
                    <ns:Contact>
                        <ns:CompanyName>Name</ns:CompanyName>
                    </ns:Contact>
                    <ns:Address>
                        <ns:CountryCode>US</ns:CountryCode>
                    </ns:Address>
                </ns:ResponsibleParty>
            </ns:Payor>
        </ns:ShippingChargesPayment>
        <ns:SpecialServicesRequested>
        </ns:SpecialServicesRequested>
        <ns:LabelSpecification>
            <ns:LabelFormatType>COMMON2D</ns:LabelFormatType>
            <ns:ImageType>ZPLII</ns:ImageType>
            <ns:LabelStockType>STOCK_4X6</ns:LabelStockType>
            <ns:LabelPrintingOrientation>TOP_EDGE_OF_TEXT_FIRST</ns:LabelPrintingOrientation>
            <ns:PrintedLabelOrigin>
                <ns:Contact>
                    <ns:CompanyName>Company</ns:CompanyName>
                    <ns:PhoneNumber>Phone</ns:PhoneNumber>
                </ns:Contact>
                <ns:Address>
                    <ns:StreetLines>Street</ns:StreetLines>
                    <ns:City>City</ns:City>
                    <ns:StateOrProvinceCode>CA</ns:StateOrProvinceCode>
                    <ns:PostalCode>Zip</ns:PostalCode>
                    <ns:CountryCode>US</ns:CountryCode>
                </ns:Address>
            </ns:PrintedLabelOrigin>
        </ns:LabelSpecification>
        <ns:RateRequestTypes>LIST</ns:RateRequestTypes>
        <ns:PackageCount>1</ns:PackageCount>
        <ns:RequestedPackageLineItems>
            <ns:SequenceNumber>1</ns:SequenceNumber>
            <ns:Weight>
                <ns:Units>LB</ns:Units>
                <ns:Value>8</ns:Value>
            </ns:Weight>
            <ns:Dimensions>
                <ns:Length>5</ns:Length>
                <ns:Width>5</ns:Width>
                <ns:Height>4</ns:Height>
                <ns:Units>IN</ns:Units>
            </ns:Dimensions>
            <ns:CustomerReferences>
                <ns:CustomerReferenceType>CUSTOMER_REFERENCE</ns:CustomerReferenceType>
                <ns:Value>CD0000002199</ns:Value>
            </ns:CustomerReferences>
            <ns:CustomerReferences>
                <ns:CustomerReferenceType>P_O_NUMBER</ns:CustomerReferenceType>
                <ns:Value>0000497600</ns:Value>
            </ns:CustomerReferences>
            <ns:SpecialServicesRequested>
                <ns:SpecialServiceTypes>DRY_ICE</ns:SpecialServiceTypes>
                <ns:SpecialServiceTypes>SIGNATURE_OPTION</ns:SpecialServiceTypes>
                <ns:DryIceWeight>
                    <ns:Units>KG</ns:Units>
                    <ns:Value>2.5</ns:Value>
                </ns:DryIceWeight>
                <ns:SignatureOptionDetail>
                    <ns:OptionType>DIRECT</ns:OptionType>
                </ns:SignatureOptionDetail>
            </ns:SpecialServicesRequested>
        </ns:RequestedPackageLineItems>
    </ns:RequestedShipment>
</ns:ProcessShipmentRequest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code i have started from documentation but it is returning no changes in the rates. I want to include DRY ICE charges

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$client = new SoapClient($path_to_wsdl, array('trace' => 1)); // Refer to http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ref.soap.php for more information

$request['WebAuthenticationDetail'] = array(
    'ParentCredential' => array(
        'Key' => getProperty('parentkey'),
        'Password' => getProperty('parentpassword')
    ),
    'UserCredential' => array(
        'Key' => getProperty('key'), 
        'Password' => getProperty('password')
    )
); 
$request['ClientDetail'] = array(
    'AccountNumber' => getProperty('shipaccount'), 
    'MeterNumber' => getProperty('meter')
);
$request['TransactionDetail'] = array('CustomerTransactionId' => ' *** Rate Request using PHP ***');
$request['Version'] = array(
    'ServiceId' => 'crs', 
    'Major' => '20', 
    'Intermediate' => '0', 
    'Minor' => '0'
);
$request['ReturnTransitAndCommit'] = true;
$request['RequestedShipment']['DropoffType'] = 'REGULAR_PICKUP'; // valid values REGULAR_PICKUP, REQUEST_COURIER, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['ShipTimestamp'] = date('c');

$request['RequestedShipment']['SpecialServicesRequested']['ShipmentSpecialServiceType']= "DRY_ICE";
$request['RequestedShipment']['specialServicesRequested']['shipmentDryIceDetail']['packageCount']= 5;
$request['RequestedShipment']['specialServicesRequested']['shipmentDryIceDetail']['totalweight']= 50;
$request['RequestedShipment']['specialServicesRequested']['ShipmentSpecialServiceType'] = 'DRY_ICE';

$request['RequestedShipment']['ServiceType'] = 'INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY'; // valid values STANDARD_OVERNIGHT, PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT, FEDEX_GROUND, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['PackagingType'] = 'YOUR_PACKAGING'; // valid values FEDEX_BOX, FEDEX_PAK, FEDEX_TUBE, YOUR_PACKAGING, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['TotalInsuredValue']=array(
    'Ammount'=>100,
    'Currency'=>'USD'
);
$request['RequestedShipment']['Shipper'] = addShipper();
$request['RequestedShipment']['Recipient'] = addRecipient();
$request['RequestedShipment']['ShippingChargesPayment'] = addShippingChargesPayment();
$request['RequestedShipment']['PackageCount'] = '1';
$request['RequestedShipment']['RequestedPackageLineItems'] = addPackageLineItem1();
```

Comment: `RequestedShipment/SpecialServicesRequested/ShipmentSpecialServiceType` like you have here always throws an error for me even though the documentation says that is correct. Also, I don't believe there is any cost difference for Dry Ice shipments. I've added a new answer with working XML as well. I was able to get it working after talking with FedEx.

Comment: Glad that you have find solution. But as i am trying to put solution through PHP i don't want to mess with WSDL. Can you please help me how i can add Dry ice in my request seeing the above code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add dry ice through the following code

```
$path_to_wsdl = "wsdl/RateService_v20.wsdl";

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$client = new SoapClient($path_to_wsdl, array('trace' => 1)); // Refer to http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ref.soap.php for more information

$request['WebAuthenticationDetail'] = array(
    'ParentCredential' => array(
        'Key' => getProperty('parentkey'),
        'Password' => getProperty('parentpassword')
    ),
    'UserCredential' => array(
        'Key' => getProperty('key'),
        'Password' => getProperty('password')
    )
);
$request['ClientDetail'] = array(
    'AccountNumber' => getProperty('shipaccount'),
    'MeterNumber' => getProperty('meter')
);
$request['TransactionDetail'] = array('CustomerTransactionId' => ' *** Rate Request using PHP ***');
$request['Version'] = array(
    'ServiceId' => 'crs',
    'Major' => '20',
    'Intermediate' => '0',
    'Minor' => '0'
);
$request['ReturnTransitAndCommit'] = true;
$request['RequestedShipment']['DropoffType'] = 'REGULAR_PICKUP'; // valid values REGULAR_PICKUP, REQUEST_COURIER, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['ShipTimestamp'] = date('c');



/* * *********Adding Dry Ice * */
$request['RequestedShipment']['SpecialServicesRequested']['SpecialServiceTypes'] = 'DRY_ICE';
$request['RequestedShipment']['SpecialServicesRequested']['DryIceWeight'] = '5';
$request['RequestedShipment']['SpecialServicesRequested']['ShipmentDryIceDetail']['PackageCount'] = '1';

$request['RequestedShipment']['ServiceType'] = 'INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY'; // valid values STANDARD_OVERNIGHT, PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT, FEDEX_GROUND, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['PackagingType'] = 'YOUR_PACKAGING'; // valid values FEDEX_BOX, FEDEX_PAK, FEDEX_TUBE, YOUR_PACKAGING, ...
$request['RequestedShipment']['TotalInsuredValue'] = array(
    'Ammount' => 100,
    'Currency' => 'USD'
);
$request['RequestedShipment']['Shipper'] = addShipper();

$request['RequestedShipment']['Recipient'] = addRecipient();
$request['RequestedShipment']['ShippingChargesPayment'] = addShippingChargesPayment();
$request['RequestedShipment']['PackageCount'] = '1';
$request['RequestedShipment']['RequestedPackageLineItems'] = addPackageLineItem1();


try {
    if (setEndpoint('changeEndpoint')) {
        $newLocation = $client->__setLocation(setEndpoint('endpoint'));
    }

    $response = $client->getRates($request);



    if ($response->HighestSeverity != 'FAILURE' && $response->HighestSeverity != 'ERROR') {
        $rateReply = $response->RateReplyDetails;
        echo '<table border="1">';
        echo '<tr><td>Service Type</td><td>Amount</td><td>Delivery Date</td></tr><tr>';
        $serviceType = '<td>' . $rateReply->ServiceType . '</td>';
        if ($rateReply->RatedShipmentDetails && is_array($rateReply->RatedShipmentDetails)) {
            $amount = '<td>$' . number_format($rateReply->RatedShipmentDetails[0]->ShipmentRateDetail->TotalNetCharge->Amount, 2, ".", ",") . '</td>';
        } elseif ($rateReply->RatedShipmentDetails && !is_array($rateReply->RatedShipmentDetails)) {
            $amount = '<td>$' . number_format($rateReply->RatedShipmentDetails->ShipmentRateDetail->TotalNetCharge->Amount, 2, ".", ",") . '</td>';
        }
        if (array_key_exists('DeliveryTimestamp', $rateReply)) {
            $deliveryDate = '<td>' . $rateReply->DeliveryTimestamp . '</td>';
        } else if (array_key_exists('TransitTime', $rateReply)) {
            $deliveryDate = '<td>' . $rateReply->TransitTime . '</td>';
        } else {
            $deliveryDate = '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        }
        echo $serviceType . $amount . $deliveryDate;
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</table>';

        printSuccess($client, $response);
    } else {
        printError($client, $response);
    }
    writeToLog($client);    // Write to log file   
} catch (SoapFault $exception) {
    printFault($exception, $client);
}
```